# Why were Anakin and Obi-Wan the only ones to wear excessive armor?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-clone-wars, obi-wan-kenobi, anakin-skywalker

In the canon animated series *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Obi-Wan and Anakin wear a great amount of armor. However, the rest of the Jedi seem to only wear armor on their arms, or even not at all. Why is this?

Comment: Because robes are really hard to animate.

Comment: Other Jedi wear armour; http://www.starwars.com/news/force-of-fashion-jedi-armor

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_apparel

Comment: Apparently because Anakin & Obi-Wan see something like 10x as much action as other Jedi during The Clone Wars. Seriously, they're pretty much the only ones doing anything.

Comment: I remember reading that Obi-Wan started practicing Form III (Soresu), after Qui-Gon was killed. Soresu is a defensive form, not so much an attacking one. It is reasonable to believe that Anakin would practice the same form as his master, and thus they would both wear at least some armour. Also, take a look at [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87651/how-did-obi-wan-so-easily-beat-anakin?rq=1) and the Jedi from *The Old Republic* trailers.

Comment: One point to add there though.......they only wear it during the series NOT during the films.

Comment: I always thought the Clone Wars animation style was really hard, spiky, and unrealistic.  So it may have looked like they were wearing armor.

Comment: It's been confirmed on more than one occasion that they were wearing armor.

Comment: The designs of characters in "The Clone Wars" is based off the designs from "Clone Wars". However, it seems like "The Clone Wars" ended up going in its own direction, as other Jedi and eventually Anakin and Obi-wan were designed with less armor.

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading/seeing something at some point that alluded to the fact that Obi-Wan wore armor that was similar to the clones because it gave him a more relatable demeanor to the clone troops he was commanding. That he did so because he saw the troopers as more than just "clones" but as individuals (i.e. Rex, Fives, Echo, so on..)

Comment: Can you find the source for your claim and provide it?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, Anakin and Obi-wan were war heroes. They were kind of poster boys. So the armor was to make them seem heroic I guess. I can’t cite anything but I know I remember reading about their war hero status.

Answer (score 0):

They weren’t the only ones to wear armor and they mainly did it to show that they actually cared for there clone troopers unlike those like Pong krell who greatly mistreated their clones

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Do you have any evidence for your assertions from the source material that you could [edit] in?